# DECODE function syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to answer the following question, which reads

[image]

I have written the following code

```
SELECT job_id, 
DECODE(job_id,A, 'Ad_Pres',
B,'St_Man',
C,'IT_PROG',
)JOBID, GRADE
FROM emplyee_grade;
ORDER BY job_id
```

Oracle is telling me "missing expression" what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Either specify a default value or remove the last comma in your decode arguments

Comment: Your query is wrong in two ways, syntactically and functionally. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your query is wrong in two ways.**

1. As already suggested by others, there is a **syntax error**, remove the last comma.
2. **Functionally**, you are doing it wrong as per the question. The question is to decode the `JOB_ID` to display the required `GRADEs` as shown in figure.

So, the correct query is :

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'AD_PRES' JOB_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'ST_MAN' JOB_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'IT_PROG' JOB_ID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'THE REST' JOB_ID FROM DUAL)
  6  SELECT job_id,
  7    DECODE(JOB_ID, 'AD_PRES','A','ST_MAN','B','IT_PROG','C','THE REST','D','DEFAULT') GRADE
  8  FROM DATA
  9  /

JOB_ID   GRADE
-------- -------
AD_PRES  A
ST_MAN   B
IT_PROG  C
THE REST D

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I wish every SQL question also has a test case to reduce the time and effort to reverse engineer, what say?

Comment: Yes, that would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECODE(job_id,'A', 'Ad_Pres',
'B','St_Man',
'C','IT_PROG', <-- take this comma away
)
```

Take away the extra comma, and I believe the A, B ,C need to be in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks @ dcp but then I get invalid character error

Comment: @Marilee remove also the last semi colon before the order by clause

Comment: The query is functionally wrong anyway. Since it won't return anything, as `JOB_ID` is being checked with `GRADE` values. It should be the other way round. See my answer.